# Sending email from Google Sheet after a cell is updated from Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

Hi i currently have this code to send an email:

```js
function sendNotification(e){
  
if(e.range.getColumn()==4 && e.value=='Air Filter'){
 var recipients = "xx@email.com";
 var subject = "Update on "+e.range.getSheet().getName();
 var body = "Air filter 50751-123 needs ordered for the Hurco"
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
 }
  
if(e.range.getColumn()==4 && e.value=='Coolant'){
 var recipients = "xx@email.com"&&"xyx@email.com";
 var subject = "Update on "+e.range.getSheet().getName();
 var body = "Coolant is needed for the Hurco"
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
 
}  
  
}
```

My question is, when a Google Form is submitted into my Google Sheet, then a certain word is submitted into a certain column, I want Google to send an email to the required recipient(s).

I have it working when I physically go into the Sheet and edit the column but I want it to work when a Form is entered. (this only works when I have the trigger to onEdit, when it is on onChange, I get an error of "TypeError: Cannot call method "getColumn" of undefined. (line 3, file "Email Notif")")

The column that it will be looking at will have 4 different words it could be looking for, and each word may be linked to different recipients. "Air filter" goes to one person while "Coolant" will go to two different people.

Thank you

Comment: The event you want is `onFormSubmit`, not onChange

Comment: I switched it to onFormSubmit and now it wont send out an email. I checked the Executions of the trigger and it seems to be completing with no failure.

Comment: sorry it's not a simple trigger, you need to install the trigger for the Form submit event.  Click the clock button in the script editor to launch the installable trigger wizard.

Comment: Please copy/paste the Execution transcript into your question. Please also share a copy of your spreadsheet, excluding any private or confidential information.

Comment: @dwmorrin What do you mean by "installable trigger wizard". Is this something not provided by Google? If it's the page where you can add triggers, then yes I have made a trigger the the script and used onFormSubmit with no luck.

Comment: @Tedinoz As for the Execution transcript, is there a way to "print" it to show each event or are you just speaking of going to (https://script.google.com/home/executions) and showing you what's on there? 
Here is the spreadsheet - [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fcsj3ZtxzscT-8R_kaXE1DU0eRWE6SlC4M24TBWWxXY/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the form - [link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1anMqaloObpo9EzzVtF3HsErWfcF4Znc9kswD5JrVj00/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Regarding installing the trigger, [documentation is here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and you should be able to select "event source" as "on form submit", choose function "sendNotification", and the next time you do a form submission, it should run.  Use [stackdriver logging, i.e. `console.log`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) to aid you in debugging this.  Also, it will not run because there is no `e.value` property of the "on form submit" event object (different from "on edit").  You must use `e.values` or `e.namedValues`.

Comment: @Freeman In the script editor, View => Execution transcript (it will display to screen). Drag your cursor over a couple of lines to highlight them, then Press "CTRL A" (Select All), and then CTRL C (Copy); the transcript is now in memory. Switch to your question, edit the question, got the the bottom and press "CRTL V" (Paste) to paste the transcript into your question. Add an appropriate heading, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an email when a Form is submitted, you need to use the ["on form submit" installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

The code must be updated to use the correct [event properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).  You were using the "on edit" event's `.value` property, but the "on form submit" event has `.values`, which is an array of values, or `.namedValues` which is an object where the form questions are the keys (i.e. the column headers of the response sheet).

The range is going to be the form submission, so there isn't much point in checking the range for column 4 like you needed to do for an edit event.

```js
function sendNotification(e) {
  var recipients = "xx@email.com";
  var subject = "Update on " + e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var body = "";
  if (e.namedValues["Item that is needed."] == 'Air Filter') {
    body = "Air filter 50751-123 needs ordered for the Hurco";
  } else if (e.namedValues["Item that is needed."] == 'Coolant') {
    recipients += ",xyx@email.com";
    body = "Coolant is needed for the Hurco";
  }
  if (body.length > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Edit:

As requested in comment, an update to include checking previous submission for duplicates, based on selected column numbers.

```js
function sendNotification(e) {
  var recipients = "xx@email.com";
  var subject = "Update on " + e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var body = "";
  if (checkForSameSubmission(e, 24, [2, 3])) { // event, hours to look back, columns to check (zero index!)
    subject += " DUPLICATE";
    body += "WARNING: DUPLICATE!\n";
  }
  if (e.namedValues["Item that is needed."] == 'Air Filter') {
    body += "Air filter 50751-123 needs ordered for the Hurco";
  } else if (e.namedValues["Item that is needed."] == 'Coolant') {
    recipients += ",xyx@email.com";
    body += "Coolant is needed for the Hurco";
  }
  if (body.length > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}

// JSON.stringify will let us compare array values as strings
function checkForSameSubmission(event, hours) {
  var sheetData = event.range.getSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  sheetData.shift(); // remove header row
  sheetData.pop(); // remove just submitted row
  var byColumns = function (_, index) { // for Array.prototype.filter
    return columns.indexOf(index) > -1;
  }
  var toStrings = function (value) { // for Array.prototype.map
    return String(value); // ensure all numbers become strings for final comparison
  };
  var thisSubmissionData = JSON.stringify(event.values.filter(byColumns).map(toStrings));
  var isSameSubmission = function (dataRow) {
    return thisSubmissionData === JSON.stringify(dataRow.filter(byColumns).map(toStrings));
  }
  return checkPreviousDataByHours(hours, sheetData, isSameSubmission);
}

function checkPreviousDataByHours(hours, data, someCallback) {
  var minusHours = Date.now() - 1000*60*60*hours;
  var lastHoursData = data.filter(function (row) { return +row[0] > minusHours; });
  return lastHoursData.some(someCallback);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, Event Objects are described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) but it's a handy trick to insert `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` in your code and the view the objects in the log. Or do much the same thing with `console.log`.

Comment: @dwmorrin this worked great! Thank you!
If you have time, could you possibly think of a way for when someone submits something and it is the same exact submission someone did 2 hours ago that it would either notify in the email that this is a duplicate or maybe some sort of notification that would pop up (doubting that is an option). I am going to guess it will be something with looking "up" in the rows above the last submission and comparing to the timestamp on the first column to see if a duplicate request was made in the same "day". Thank you.

Comment: @dwmorrin I copied the code but it doesn't quite seem to send the message you have above about being a duplicate. Still sends the same submission.

Comment: @Freeman - not too surprised by that, as I did not try to run it myself!  Could you try to debug it yourself? My test looks at all the values of the form submission except the timestamp... if anything else is different, then it assumes its a different response.  Maybe you want to test for something specific?  Should I not test certain values?

Comment: @Freeman try it again - I had some mistakes, but I verified that it does run now properly

Comment: @dwmorrin to your comment above - what if it would test for just two of the columns? In my script I broke out "machine" as a variable. `var machine = e.namedValues["Machine"];` So the "Machine" and the "Item that is needed" could be different each time and would reduce the amount of `if` statements I need to write. Someones name could be different but requested the same item by accident. Bob requested a Filter for the Hurco at 2:30pm, then Clara requested a Filter for the Hurco at 3:00pm which would trip the email to say it was a duplicate. But if it was for a different machine, it wouldnt.

Comment: @Freeman - I added the option to specify which columns to check by supplying an array of column numbers, zero indexed.